# Linq to XML query... Issues with element name

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to query an xml file for a specific set of values. Below is part of the xml file I'm trying to query.

```
<Troubleshooter guid="5f159d5d-4dec-4caf-81e5-645d77e05c84">
<Name>Battery</Name>
<AnalysisLog>
  <LogEntry guid="76e4b077-bb50-4000-9563-7f5aa0c9dc26">
    <Name>Battery Information</Name>
    <Severity>Informational</Severity>
    <Description></Description>
    <Details>
      <Detail guid="118bf18a-13d4-4226-b207-f2ae1638de8b">
        <Name>Battery ID</Name>
        <Value> 198311-85MO06047</Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="85b01a9b-bb18-4f71-8d12-6f7dec4b3705">
        <Name>Manufacturer</Name>
        <Value>11-85</Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="1b9d5465-63f4-4c5d-8259-93effc455084">
        <Name>Manufacture Date</Name>
        <Value></Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="2229029f-aa9e-4591-989a-32223a114538">
        <Name>Serial Number</Name>
        <Value> 1983</Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="24e6973f-f544-4a33-876d-359ebc56336e">
        <Name>Chemistry</Name>
        <Value>LION</Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="8676c4f7-8918-4007-af80-76e308ca983c">
        <Name>Long Term</Name>
        <Value>1</Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="8800d772-7da3-48a1-b1e4-fc86df0e49cf">
        <Name>Sealed</Name>
        <Value>0</Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="17d29a01-f010-4f66-bf60-c121e35cfc2b">
        <Name>Cycle Count</Name>
        <Value></Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="beb3f51a-9d89-42ad-81c4-5f9b7f682fa4">
        <Name>Design Capacity</Name>
        <Value>32249</Value>
      </Detail>
      <Detail guid="b42aa79e-8ee8-44ae-8a11-5fe87cf2822b">
        <Name>Last Full Charge</Name>
        <Value>32249</Value>
      </Detail>
    </Details>
  </LogEntry>
</AnalysisLog>
```

Now, the code I'm trying to use to get the value is as shown below:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim datapath As String = "c:\energyrep.xml"
        Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Load(datapath)
        Dim dcValue = _
              From dc In xelement.Elements("detail") _
              Where CStr(dc.Element("name").Value) = "Design Capacity" _
              Select dc
        For Each xEle As XElement In dcValue
            MessageBox.Show(xEle.Element("value").Value)
        Next xEle

        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I think the problem is with the details element name. I it has the specific guid. I would think since it closes with "/detail" that you would be able to query the header the same way. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: CLARIFYING

I'm looking for an element "value" nested in a "detail" element, along with a "name" element that has a value of "Design Capacity". I need it to return the "32249" value from:

```
<Detail guid="beb3f51a-9d89-42ad-81c4-5f9b7f682fa4">
 <Name>Design Capacity</Name>
 <Value>32249</Value>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a specific detail element or an entire list? Your LINQ will find all of the detail elements where the name is Design Capacity, even if the Log Entry is unrelated.

Comment: I'm looking for an element "value" nested in a "detail" element, along with a "name" element that has a value of "Design Capacity".

I need it to return the "32249" value as show above in the edit.

Comment: Will you only have one detail element with the name value of Design Capacity for the entire file? Or will you have one (or more) per Log Entry?

Comment: There will only be one element with "Design Capacity" as it's value. I will also do another query for the value of "Last Full Charge".

Answer (score 0):

XML is case-sensitive. If you are looking for `Detail` elements, then you need to search for `Detail`, not `detail`.

```
    Dim dcValue = _
          From dc In xelement.Elements("Detail") _
          Where CStr(dc.Element("Name").Value) = "Design Capacity" _
          Select dc
    For Each xEle As XElement In dcValue
        MessageBox.Show(xEle.Element("Value").Value)
    Next xEle
```

Comment: I won't be able to try this until tomorrow when I have access to my project, but that would explain why it wasn't working. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: So I actually was able to generate the xml that I'm searching and try this code out. I'm still returning no results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `Descendents` instead of `Element`.

Comment: I've tried Descendents, and no luck. I have no idea why this is not working as intended. It is working with similar XML files. Are the additional attributes in the Detail element causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

Here We Go...(C#)

```
        var readSP = from a in xd.Descendants("Detail")
                     where a.Element("Name").Value == "Design Capacity"
                     select a.Element("Value").Value;
```